# DependencyProperty binding firing only once

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have a multibinding converter bound to a dependency property on a usercontrol. The converter seems to be fired once at initialisation, but does not fire again when its multibinding items raise changed notification.

Im not sure but I suspect the issue may be that the binding is being overwritten.

Ill post all the code I think is relevant. Please let me know if Im missing anything.

XAML Binding to Dependency property ** EDITED **:

```
<views:TextBlockComboBox.SelectedIndex>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource UIDToIndexConverter}">
                <Binding Path="DataLayer.SupplierUID"></Binding>
                <Binding Path="CoreSuppliers"></Binding>
                <Binding Path="DataLayer" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </views:TextBlockComboBox.SelectedIndex>
```

UIDToLayerConverter class :

```
public class UIDToIndexConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(
            object[] values,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {

                ILayer layer = (ILayer)values[0];

                long? UID = (long?)values[0];

                ObservableCollection<IMaterialList> materialLists = (ObservableCollection<IMaterialList>)values[1];

                foreach (IMaterialList materialList in materialLists)
                {
                    if (materialList.UID.Equals(UID))
                    {
                        return materialLists.IndexOf(materialList);
                    }
                }

                return 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(
            object value,
            Type[] targetTypes,
            object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Dependency Property as set in TextBlockComboBox

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedIndexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedIndex",
            typeof(int),
            typeof(TextBlockComboBox),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(SelectedIndexPropertyChangedCallback)


public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)GetValue(SelectedIndexProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetCurrentValue(SelectedIndexProperty, value);
            }
        }

private static void SelectedIndexPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject controlInstance, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
        }
            );
```

**EDIT** Working binding

```
<views:TextBlockComboBox.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LayerEditConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="DataLayer" />
                    <Binding>
                        <Binding.Source>
                            <system:String>Core</system:String>
                        </Binding.Source>
                    </Binding>

                </MultiBinding>
            </views:TextBlockComboBox.Visibility>
```

**EDIT** I have since found that if I remove the binding on the usercontrol to the selectedindex dependency property the converter fires.

```
<ComboBox 
            x:Name="ThisComboBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items, ElementName=ThisUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ThisUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=ThisUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}" --WITHOUT THIS IN CONVERTER FIRES__
            SelectionChanged="selectedItemChanged"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayPath, ElementName=ThisUserControl, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         />
```

Comment: Are you sure your multi-binding items raise changed notification?  `CoreSuppliers` looks like a collection and changing a collection doesn't necessarily raise `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Perhaps not the source of your problem, but you should use `SetValue` instead of `SetCurrentValue` in the SelectedIndex setter.

Comment: @Bahman_Aries Good point, from the converter code we can conclude that it's an `ObservableCollection<IMaterialList>`. It won't trigger the binding when a CollectionChanged event is raised.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the responses. It appears I had missed a binding condition out of the multi binding in me playing around trying to get it working. I had found in other multibinding conditions that what you said was true. To get around this issue I have added a binding to include the DataLayer property which does call RaisePropertyChanged. Should this not cause the converter to fire again regardless of no propertychanged notification from the other 2 binding elements?

Comment: Also as an aside I have another converter setting the visibility property of my usercontrol and this fires no problem. This is why I get the impression the problem is to do with me binding to a dependency property. Ill include the working binding xaml at the bottom of the post.

Comment: In multi-binding whenever any binding property changes, source property updates accordingly and therefore convert method gets called. So if it still doesn't work, something else must have caused the problem. have you tried Clemens suggestion?

Comment: Yes tried Clemens suggestion

Comment: Ok I seem to be making progress. When I remove the binding to the property on the usercontrol it fires the converter again. Ill try and make some progress then update the question.